# Mergesort in Python, my first sorting algorithm, what went wrong?

Tags: python, sorting, merge

```
def mergesort(a):
    if len(a)<=1:
        return a

    else:
        mid=len(a)/2
        mergesort(a[:mid])
        mergesort(a[mid:])
        auxa=[]
        j=0
        k=mid
        while j<mid and k<len(a):
            if a[j]<a[k]:
                auxa.append(a[j])
                j+=1
            else:
                auxa.append(a[k])
                k+=1

        if j==mid:
            auxa.extend(a[k:])

        if k==len(a):
            auxa.extend(a[j:mid])

        a=auxa


        return a

testlist=[3,2,1]   
print mergesort(testlist)
```

the result I got is  2 1 3

any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do not ignore the returned value from internal `mergesort()` calls

Answer (score 4):

Your function mergesort returns a new list, and does not modify the one you supplied it, as you seem to expect it to be doing. So when you call `mergesort(a[:mid])` for example, what you get back is a new sorted version of those elements, while the original `a[:mid]` stays exactly the same.

EDIT: The issue here is the way python list slicing works. When you say `a[:mid]`, python creates a 'copy' ( let's not worry about the exact *type* of copy ) of the original. Now when you modify this copy in a function, all you're doing is changing the references in it to point to new integers, not modifying the original in any way. Here's some code to flesh this out:

```
def change(a):
    a[1] = 0

a = [1, 2, 3]
change(a)
a
>> [1, 0, 3]

a = [1, 2, 3]
change(a[:2])
a
>> [1, 2, 3]
```

EDIT 2: Copying back the values done correctly (as suggested by (abamert) in the comments):

```
def mergesort(a):
  if len(a)<=1:
    return a

  else:
    mid=len(a)/2
    a = mergesort(a[:mid]) + mergesort(a[mid:])
    auxa=[]
    j=0
    k=mid
    while j<mid and k<len(a):
        if a[j]<a[k]:
            auxa.append(a[j])
            j+=1
        else:
            auxa.append(a[k])
            k+=1

    if j==mid:
        auxa.extend(a[k:])

    if k==len(a):
        auxa.extend(a[j:mid])


    return auxa
```

This are obviously better ways to do this with less copying involved, but I think this solution is slightly more relevant to the issue with the original code.

Comment: Good explanation, but I think you also want to provide the _solution_. Just do `a[:mid] = mergesort(a[:mid])` if you want to change the first half in place. Or, probably better, use `a = mergesort(a[:mid]) + mergesort(a[mid:])` to created a new sorted list out of the two sorted halves.

Comment: i don't see `a[index] = value` anywhere in the OP's code i.e., it doesn't matter whether `a` parts are passed as a copy or not, `a` is not changed anyway. `local_a = whatever` has no influence on outside world unless it is returned from the function. But OP ignores the returned value from `mergesort()` <-- this is the real issue.

Comment: I suppose it is a matter of interpretation. Your point of view is that OP intended to get the return value of his function and use it, but forgot. The fact that he has a return statement supports this. My point of view is that he expected the change to happen to the passed array. The fact that he attempts to do `a = auxa` supports this. Depending on which one you agree with more, the issue is either slice-copy or OP ignoring return value, arguing which is the "real" one does not make too much sense to me.

Comment: `local_a = whatever` .... I agree, of course. Point is it may not have been obvious to OP that it was indeed local a. But semantics, really.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with:

```
from collections import deque

def mergesort(array):
    if len(array) <= 1: return array

    midpoint = len(array) / 2

    left_array = deque(mergesort(array[:midpoint]))
    right_array = deque(mergesort(array[midpoint:]))

    merged_array = deque([])

    while len(left_array) and len(right_array):
        if left_array[0] < right_array[0]:
            merged_array.append(left_array.popleft())
        else:
            merged_array.append(right_array.popleft())

    merged_array.extend(left_array)
    merged_array.extend(right_array)

    return merged_array

print mergesort([3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: `pop(0)` is `O(n)` for lists, it makes your algorithm quadratic instead of usual `O(n*log n)` for mergesort. You could try `collections.deque()` instead of the `merged_array` list. `while left_array and right_array:` works as is. After the first loop either `left_array` or `right_array` is empty. You could use `merged_array.extend(left_array); merged_array.extend(right_array);` instead of the last two loops. To support Python 3, you could use `//` (floor division).